# Django with uwsgi+nginx serving on http, but once i add listen on 443 and ssl on; doesnt work anymore

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, https

I am trying to put my site live, and it work fine on http, but when to use ssl certificates and https I add listen to 443 and ssl on in /etc/nginx/sites-available/drlandivar.conf it say insecure connection.

(its 3 domains, pointing to one project)

here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/drlandivar.conf

```
    upstream django {
    server 0.0.0.0:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name drlandivar.com www.drlandivar.com;
    return  301 https://drlandivar.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name doutorlandivar.com www.doutorlandivar.com;
    return  301 https://doutorlandivar.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name doctorlandivar.com www.doctorlandivar.com;
    return  301 https://doctorlandivar.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name drlandivar.com www.drlandivar.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/drlandivar.com/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/drlandivar.com/server.key;

    location /media  {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/static; 
    }

    location / {
    include /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/uwsgi_params;
    proxy_pass https://django;
    proxy_redirect off;
    include proxy_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name doutorlandivar.com www.doutorlandivar.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/doutorlandivar.com/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/doutorlandivar.com/server.key;

    location /media  {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/static; 
    }

    location / {
    include /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/uwsgi_params;
    proxy_pass https://django;
    proxy_redirect off;
    include proxy_params;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name doctorlandivar.com www.doctorlandivar.com;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/doctorlandivar.com/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/doctorlandivar.com/server.key;

    location /media  {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/media;  
    }

    location /static {
        alias /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/static; 
    }

    location / {
    include /opt/virtualenv/landivarpj/uwsgi_params;
    proxy_pass https://django;
    proxy_redirect off;
    include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

my /etc/nginx/proxy_params

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

in my django project i have in settings:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

i believe its something wrong in proxy_params or in the proxy_pass https://django;

regards

Answer (score 0):

proxy_pass https://django; # This setting may be wrong.

In normal uwsgi service serve with uwsgi protocol, You can use uwsgi_pass,and one server do not need upstream,upstream protocol may be wrong, It is certainly not https.

Your url setting order is wrong too,the nginx url match order is reverse.
My English is poor,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

oups the problem was actually with my ssl certificate, they where self signed and firefox was not accepting them, doing new ssl with lets encrypt actually solved my problem